# why the graddle update failed while testing my first flutter hello world app

Tags: android, flutter

I am totally new to the mobile application development, I have started with flutter and I am using Microsoft visual code editor for development. But while When I am testing the hello world app in my android mobile it throws the graddle update failed error. Please let me know the reasons why it is happening.

Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done                         0.5s
[!] Gradle threw an error while trying to update itself. Retrying the update...
Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZjbCH.png)

Comment: please post the full exception.

Comment: I have added the screenshot of error, Can you please watch and help me.

Comment: Please follow this https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/25116

Comment: I don't have .zip .. may be

Comment: Did the link help?